# Choosing the earliest date per record when equal dates are present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with multiple dates per record. Example of the table:

| identifier | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1985-01-01 | ex1 |
| a | 1985-01-01 | ex2 |
| a | 1985-01-03 | ex3 |
| b | 1990-01-05 | ex1 |
| b | 1990-05-10 | ex4 |
| c | 1987-01-01 | ex1 |
| c | 1987-01-01 | ex3 |
| d | 1986-01-01 | ex1 |
| d | 1986-01-01 | ex3 |

I found out how to extract the earliest date in a group using:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('identifier')['date'].idxmin()]
```

However, when I have two equal dates, as the column value is sorted in alphabetical order, I end up choosing always the first alphabetic value.
I would like to find a way to randomize such behavior whenever I have equal dates, in order to pick:

- the first value the 1st time
- the second value the 2nd time
- the third value (whenever present) the 3rd time

and restart accordingly

Is there a way to use the formula above together with a condition or a randomize method? How can I do that?

Expected output :

| identifier | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1985-01-01 | ex1 |
| b | 1990-01-05 | ex1 |
| c | 1987-01-01 | ex3 |
| d | 1986-01-01 | ex1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the rows with the max date, then [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) a random one.

Either with two `groupby`:

```
out = (df[df['date'].eq(df.groupby('identifier')['date'].transform('min'))]
        .groupby('identifier').sample(n=1)
      )
```

Or with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('identifier', group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda g: g[g['date'].eq(g['date'].min())].sample(n=1))
      )
```

Example output:

```
  identifier       date value
1          a 1985-01-01   ex2
3          b 1990-01-05   ex1
6          c 1987-01-01   ex3
8          d 1986-01-01   ex3
```

Other possible output:

```
  identifier       date value
0          a 1985-01-01   ex1
3          b 1990-01-05   ex1
5          c 1987-01-01   ex1
7          d 1986-01-01   ex1
```

##### iterating all possibilities

If you want to iterate on first the first max, then the second, etc. (which is **not random**):

```
g1 = df.groupby('identifier')['date']
g2 = df.groupby(['identifier', 'date'])

df2 = (df[df['date'].eq(g1.transform('min'))]
       .assign(n=g2.cumcount())
      )

for n, g in df2.groupby('n'):
    print(f'iteration: {n+1}')
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
iteration: 1
  identifier       date value  n
0          a 1985-01-01   ex1  0
3          b 1990-01-05   ex1  0
5          c 1987-01-01   ex1  0
7          d 1986-01-01   ex1  0
iteration: 2
  identifier       date value  n
1          a 1985-01-01   ex2  1
6          c 1987-01-01   ex3  1
8          d 1986-01-01   ex3  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) :

```
out = (df.groupby(["identifier", "date"], group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda s: s.sample(1, random_state=0))
         .sort_values(["identifier", "date"])
         .groupby("identifier", as_index=False).first()
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  identifier        date value
0          a  1985-01-01   ex2
1          b  1990-01-05   ex1
2          c  1987-01-01   ex3
3          d  1986-01-01   ex3
```